# Cache MP3 Audio Files for Offline Access

Tags: vue.js, html5-audio, service-worker, offline-caching

I have built a Single Page Application in Vue, but now I get a request for an offline version, where you can listen to a mp3 file offline, e.g. in the Plane or in areas with no signal.

Is it possible with Vue, a local storage or the service-worker to add a audio file to the local storage (download for offline listening), and have some kind of expiration date, almost like you have on a native app, e.g. Spotify?

Comment: It is possible and there are open source implementations like [this with worker](https://github.com/leonardovilarinho/vue-offline-worker). There are also plenty of options when I googled like `vue offline storage`. You can add TTL or TTI values to caches if you definitely need expiration.

Comment: Cool, I will look into that. It looks like the worker use localforage, so I will see how it will work with mp3 files. Thanks for giving me the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using IndexDB, which can store binary data as blobs without explicit base64 encoding:

- [MDN IndexDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)
- [*Blob Support For IndexedDB Landed on Chrome*](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/07/Blob-support-for-IndexedDB-landed-on-Chrome-Dev)
- [*Storing ...[Binary] Files in IndexDB*](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/)

Jake A wrote a nice library to interface with IndexDB more cleanly:

https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb

Answer (score 0):

Check the **Unified Media Pipeline (UMP)** as a solution: [Service Worker Caching, PlaybackRate and Blob URLs for Audio and Video on Chrome for Android](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/ump)